# How to implement Horizontal and Vertical Scrolling in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling

Curently I'm using `ViewPager` to achieve Horizontal and Vertical Scrolling in a `RecyclerView` with `LinearLayoutManager` set to `LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL`.

Is there any better approach to do the same?

Comment: Did you receive any feasible solution for same?

Comment: Please try this solution

https://irpdevelop.wordpress.com/2016/02/10/horizontal-recyclerview-inside-a-vertical-recyclerview/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a RecyclerView with both horizontal and vertical scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36408266/create-a-recyclerview-with-both-horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling)

Answer (score 0):

you have to set layout manager to recycler view with orientation as Horizontal

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getOmniActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

Comment: That will make the list only horizontally scrollable.

Comment: what do you want to achieve. Can you be more specific.  Or you can use Staggered GridView.

Comment: I want a list similar to facebook app. The ads are scrollable horizontally and the vertical list has news feed.

Comment: Then you have to make RecyclerView inside RecyclerView.. That is possible. But performance wise it may slow your phone.

Answer (score 0):

You cant set both horizontal and vertical at a time, you can set either....if you want same approach then use vertical scrollbar with horizontal recyclerview.

You can create horizontal recyclerview as

```
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
    = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView myList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```