# Create a RecyclerView with both horizontal and vertical scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, scroll, android-recyclerview

Over the past few weeks I've been learning to use the `RecyclerView`. I need to implement a horizontal list, ie, that by turning the device in landscape mode like so:

[image]

I found the best solution for this (how to create the horizontal displacement of `RecyclerView`, [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/)), but encountered another problem. The item `RecyclerView` was larger than the height of the device (in landscape, horizontal), so I need to create a vertical and horizontal displacement, simultaneously.

I looked at the Android Developer methods for the `LayoutManager` class, but my skills are not high enough to understand most of the methods. I also tried putting a `RecyclerView` vertically inside another `RecyclerView` horizontally with all the content, but I get error:

> IllegalStateException: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager

To rememedy this I removed all `<View ... />` elements from the XML file, but this does not give any results.

To clarify what I am asking: is it possible to have my layout scroll both horizontally and vertically, and if you could explain how I would appreciate it.

Comment: how about 2-dimensional gallery as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754445/how-to-make-a-2-dimension-image-gallery-with-both-horizontal-and-vertical-scroll

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was so angry about all the problems that had tended with the application that had not thought about the easiest solution.

In a `RecyclerView` consists of two XML files, the main one where the RecyclerView is declared and another with content.

The simplest solution was to introduce the `RecyclerView` within a `ScrollView`. So I can move all items at a time thanks to `ScrollView` vertically and horizontally I can move the items thanks to `RecyclerView` in landscape mode.

**`activity_main.xml`**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/cardIn_margin_ext">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal" />

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Simple and genius!

Comment: if a parent is a scrollview, the child cannot be a scrollview too.. this results in ambiguity wen rendered. Niiice attempt to trouble android OS

Comment: Congrats on your solution!  But if you want to have a LOT of both vertical and horizontal scrolling, you need the RecyclerView to handle both directions (like in my case, sort of a spreadsheet).  Anyone out there with a solution that actually uses only RecyclerViews?

Comment: We need to add NestedScrollView instead of Scrollview

Comment: This is not working .. you have to use FixedGridLayoutManager for that.

Comment: The problem here is that `ScrollView` isn't aware of what's currently visible and can't recycle views. You'll end up rendering everything in the `RecyclerView`, even the non visible rows.

Answer (score 15):

The accepted answer did'nt work for me. I had to use the HorizontalScrollView instead of simple ScrollView.

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_margin="@dimen/cardIn_margin_ext">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal" />
</HorizontalScrollView >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_margin="@dimen/cardIn_margin_ext">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" />
```